# Curve that lies on a solution surface

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose the solution surface is given as $$f(x,y,u)=0$$. A curve $$C$$ lies on the solution surface. What does this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that if the point $(x,y,u) \in C$, then $f(x,y,u) = 0$.

Comment: Which really is just $$f(C)=0?$$?

Comment: @user if you like, this can be said.

Comment: On a tangent, why do we speak about a curve C on a surface in the context of a boundary condition for a differential equation?

Comment: @user likely because you want to claim something about all curves in the solution surface with some nice properties

Comment: And the other definition for $$f(C)=0$$ is really just called the surface of constant f?

Comment: @user i think "$f$ is constant"  and $f=0$ are not the same, but latter is special case of the former

Comment: It's becoming clearer and I certainly agree with your statement above. But what exactly is 'constant' in this case? (non-infinity?)

Comment: @user for example, the surface where $f(x,y,u) = \sqrt{2}$ would certainly be a constant but non-zero $f$

Comment: If there exists a vector field tangent to the surface of constant f at every point of the curve,  then all tangent vector to the curve are parallel to each and every other tangent vector, am I right?

Comment: @user this is beyond me at this point